# Rspec/Paperclip: validation fails even with following documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, shoulda, paperclip-validation

Here is my validation:

```
describe User
  it { should validate_attachment_size(:avatar).less_than(20.megabytes) }
end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_attachment :avatar, :content_type => { :content_type => /image/ }, size: { in: 0..20.megabytes }, allow_blank: true
end
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_attachment_size(:avatar).less_than(20.megabytes) }
       Attachment avatar must be between  and 20971520 bytes
```

Not sure why this is failing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might be this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/376